# Read a large TAD data with Dask

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a very large dataframe. It was originally a TAD file. Someone saved it with CSV extension.

I was trying to read it in pandas but it takes hours, even with [chunksize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) parameter.

```
start = time.time()
#read data in chunks of 1 million rows at a time
chunk = pd.read_csv(
  '/.../estrapola_articoli.csv',
  sep='\t',
  lineterminator='\r',
  chunksize=1000000) # <-- here
end = time.time()
print("Read csv with chunks: ",(end-start),"sec")
articoli = pd.concat(chunk)
```

I've read about Dask and I've tried the following:

```
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_csv(
  '/.../estrapola_articoli.csv',
  sep='\t',
  lineterminator='\r')
```

Unfortunately, I've got this error

> ValueError: Sample is not large enough to include at least one row of
> data. Please increase the number of bytes in `sample` in the call to
> `read_csv`/`read_table`
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/dask/backends.py in
> wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
> 125                     return func(*args, **kwargs)
> 126                 except Exception as e:
> --> 127                     raise type(e)(
> 128                         f"An error occurred while calling the {funcname(func)} "
> 129                         f"method registered to the {self.backend} backend.\n"
>
> ValueError: An error occurred while calling the read_csv method
> registered to the pandas backend. Original Message: Sample is not
> large enough to include at least one row of data. Please increase the
> number of bytes in `sample` in the call to `read_csv`/`read_table`

So I used [sample](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.read_csv.html):

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_csv(
  '/.../estrapola_articoli.csv',
  sep='\t',
  lineterminator='\r',
  sample=1000000)  # 1MB
```

It gives me the same error. I could try significantly increasing the sample size further, but this could lead to inefficient computations if the sample is too large.

Any help to read this file?

Comment: Reading in big data from disk is never going to be efficient. However, I recently tried `polars` library, and am very impressed so far. It works similarly to `pandas`, but leverages parallel operations amongst other efficiency and performance gains. I tested with a ~4gb csv, and `polars` read it about 4.5x faster than `pandas`. You could give it a try with `scan_csv` to work through the data without reading it all into memory at once

Comment: I gave it a try, but I cannot specify parameter like , sep='\t', lineterminator='\r'. Maybe I should open a new question

Comment: Check the documentation here: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.scan_csv.html . There are `separator`  and `eol_char` arguments that can be used if needed

Comment: Question: we don't know what TAD is, is it really possible that your lines are so long?